# How to tell if a URL points to file that can be opened for reading

Tags: url, inputstream, bufferedreader, streamreader

How can I tell if a URL points to a file, and that file can be opened for reading without actually reading the file (in case it's too big).

Answer (score 0):

In Java use `nio.file.Files` with `isReadable(Path path)`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: Will this work if the file is not a local file and is located on a remote server?

Comment: If you have a connection to the remote server and the correct `Path`, then yes.